# How to use the ALL or ANY operator in your query in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

Question: List the part number, part description, unit price, and item class for each part that has a unit price greater than the unit price of every part in item class AP. Use either the ALL or ANY
operator in your query.

This is what I am trying but it's not working...help

```
SELECT Part.PartNum, Part.Description, Part.Price, Part.Class
FROM Part
WHERE [Price]> ANY 
AND Part.Class="AP";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the correct syntax would be something like this:

```
SELECT Part.PartNum, Part.Description, Part.Price, Part.Class
FROM Part
WHERE [Price]> ANY 
(Select Price from Part Where
Class="AP");
```

The important part is that what you place after Any is a subquery written in parenthesis.

Here's a reference which I used for formatting my answer. [SQL Subqueries (Microsoft Access SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192664%28v=office.14%29.aspx)